# ASP.NET TreeView events

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, events, treeview

I have TreeView and ListView which are needed to display folders and files.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMMk6.png)

On TreeNode click i want to display files in this folder, but *SelectedNodeChanged* event doesn't work. And same problem with TreeNodePopulate.
I tried to use this example from msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.selectednodestyle(v=vs.110).aspx

but it doesnt stop in breakpoint.

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Fill Tree root
    Tree.FillTree(TreeView1, ListView1, ViewState);

}

protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //don't stopped there
    var p = 15;
}

protected void TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    //don't stopped there
    var x = 3;
}
```

```
<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 651px">
   <table bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
    <td style ="border-right: 1px solid black; width: 369px; overflow: auto;">
        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" Height="326px" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer" EnableClientScript="false" 
            NodeIndent="15" Width="292px" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged1" OnTreeNodePopulate="TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate">
            <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
            <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA" />
            <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalPadding="0px"
                VerticalPadding="0px" />
            <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="2px"
                NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Images/folder.gif" />
        </asp:TreeView> 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 954px">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
         <LayoutTemplate>
            Name
            <br />
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("\nName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            <br />
        </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </td>
    <td style="width: 155px">

        &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Example not working code please.

Comment: I loaded up the code and it seems to work fine. I changed the page_load to manually add some items and removed a form tag from my master page but otherwise the TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged1 was always called. Do you have AutoEventWireup="true" set in your master page?

Comment: Also my populate was not called but that is by design
"Occurs when a node with its PopulateOnDemand property set to true is expanded in the TreeView control" that requires more setup, basically you can 'lazy load' subnodes at the time they are made visible instead of loading everything up front.